# Conditional Clauses not working as Expected

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, stack

I am facing trouble with the following piece of code. values and minStack are both stacks initialised, and the top values of both the stacks are same. However, the first code snippet fails to go into the if condition while the latter does. I am unable to debug this.

```
   public void pop() {

        System.out.println(values.peek()); // prints -1024
        System.out.println(minStack.peek()); // prints -1024

        if(values.pop() == minStack.peek()) { 
        // Condition not fulfilled
            minStack.pop();
        }
    }
```

However, the following works as expected.

```
    public void pop() {
        int valTop = values.pop();
        int minTop = minStack.peek();

        if(valTop == minTop) { 
             minStack.pop();
        }   

    }
```

Please help as I am unable to figure out the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (probably) have the stacks initialized as `Stack<Integer>`, that means they store Integer instances. Integer is an object (notice the uppercase I) and comparing two object instances using `==` compares their addresses in memory. Not what you want. `new Integer(1) != new Integer(1)` as you are creating two objects which obviously don't point to the same memory address.

On the other hand, using `==` to compare two primitives compares their value, not their address.

You might want to change the stack initializations to be `Stack<int>`, but you can't do that (yet) as generics in Java can't be primitive.

To fix this, use the overriden `.equals(Object obj)` method in Integer which calls `.intValue()` on both Integer objects and actually compares two ints.

So, replace

```
if(values.pop() == minStack.peek())
```

with

```
if(values.pop().equals(minStack.peek()))
```

The second example works because when you assign an Integer object to a variable of type int, the Integer is automatically converted to int. The opposite can also be done via the process of autoboxing.

Comment: This is it! Thanks, you just saved me from killing myself.

Comment: And to specifically explain why your second snippet _does_ work, this code: `int valTop = values.pop();` is syntax sugar. The compiler sees this, knows it makes no sense (`pop()` returns an `Integer`, which isn't the same as an `int`), but then assumes you intend to 'auto-unbox' the value, and acts as if you wrote `int valTop = values.pop().intValue()`. Now the `if (valTop == minTop)` comparison is between primitives, i.e. compares value.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing object references with `==`. Use

```
if (values.pop().intValue() == minStack.peek()) {
```

**or**

```
if (values.pop().equals(minStack.peek())) {
```